# ¿Cómo comentar más de una línea en Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

He encontrado CONTROL+K+C COMENTA Y DESCOMENTA CTRL+K+U,
Cuando lo utilizo en archivos .js, me comenta línea a línea con el doble //.
Pero no en bloque /**/ con archivos .html si funciona correctamente.
¿Alguien sabe el por qué en .js no me comenta en bloque.?
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> es alternar comentario de linea. Puedes editarlo desde la configuración de editor buscando alternar comentario en bloque. Yo lo tengo modificado por eso no recuerdo cual es el predefinido.

Puedes buscarlo usando la Paleta de comandos (Command palette):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> → shortcuts → toggle block comment

Comment: Perfecto. gracias

Answer (score 0):

### WINDOWS

Selecciona una el bloque de código que quieras comentar, y haces la siguiente combinación:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

En VS Code 1.70.1 (Windows 2022) puedes usar:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

además puedes descargar betters comments, una extension muy util si se trata de comentar en vscode https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaron-bond.better-comments

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

A mi en windows me funcionan estos dos comandos:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> y sin soltar <kbd>ctrl</kbd> presiono la letra <kbd>c</kbd>